# How to find delta from a given epsilon in multiple dimensions

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{y-z}$. $\lim\limits_{{x,y,z} \to {2,2,1}} \frac{x}{y-z}=2$. If $\epsilon=.5$, find $\delta$.

Here's (grossely) what I have done up to now:

$y \in  [2-\delta, 2+\delta]$ and $z \in [1- \delta, 1+ \delta]$
$\implies ((2-\delta)-(1-\delta))\le(y-z)\le((2+\delta)-(1-\delta))$

$\implies 1\le(y-z)\le(2\delta+1)$

We know $\lvert\frac{x}{y-z}-2\rvert\le0.5$

$\lvert\frac{x}{y-z}-2\rvert=\lvert\frac{(x-2(y-z))}{y-z}\rvert\le\lvert\frac{x-2(2\delta+1)}{1}\rvert=\lvert\ (x-2)-4\delta\rvert\le|\delta-4\delta|=3\delta$

So $\delta=3\epsilon=1.5$. However, my answer doesn't appear to be correct. Where did I go wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: $((2-\delta)-(1-\delta))\le(y-z)\le((2+\delta)-(1-\delta))$ should be $((2-\delta)-(1+ \delta))\le(y-z)\le((2+\delta)-(1-\delta))$, which changes the rest of what follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other problems:

$\lvert\frac{(x-2(y-z))}{y-z}\rvert\le\lvert\frac{x-2(2\delta+1)}{1}\rvert$ is not true. The change in denominator is justifiable (after making the necessary correction from the error I've already pointed out), but note that you have made the numerator substitution as large as possible, even though it is being subtracted from $x$.

$\lvert\ (x-2)-4\delta\rvert\le|\delta-4\delta|$ is not true. $|a| \le |c|$ does not in general imply that $|a+b| \le |c+b|$. However, this is easily rectifiable, because $\lvert\ (x-2)-4\delta\rvert\le\lvert\ (x-2)\rvert +\lvert4\delta\rvert\le5\delta$.

$\lvert\frac{x}{y-z}-2\rvert < 3\delta \implies \delta = 3\epsilon$ You've got that backwards. Remember: we need $\lvert\frac{x}{y-z}-2\rvert < \epsilon$, so what you need here would be $\epsilon = 3\delta$  (if $3\delta$ had been correct in the first place.)

Comment: Can you provide the full proof to this? With the scratch work and what we will be taking $\delta$ as?

Comment: @HKT - I could, but homework problems are intended to give you practice in figuring these things out yourself. If I just hand you the answer, you will never master the concepts.

Comment: Or maybe by showing me the scratch work you could teach me as to how these questions will be tackled and this will allow me to move on and continue studying for my midterm.. this isn't a homework question btw.

Comment: @HKT - You need $\left|{x\over y-z}-2\right| < {1\over 2}$ or $\frac 32 < {x\over y-z} < \frac 52$. Let's arbitrarily restrict $|y - 2|<0.1, |z - 1| < 0.1$. Then $\frac 45 < y - z < \frac 65$ so $\frac 56x < \frac x{y-z} < \frac 54x$. Now we need $\frac 32 < \frac 56 x$ and $\frac 54x < \frac52$, or $2 - \frac 15 < x < 2$. No good, since we need to see what happens when $x > 2$. So lets cut the range on $y, z$ to $0.05$, which leads to $1.65 < x < 2.25$, which is satisfied when $|x-2|<0.25$. If $\|(x,y,z) - (2,2,1)\| < 0.05$, then all 3 inequalities are satisfied. Now flip it around to prove.